OpenAPI generator creates classes based on the field in the request body, not the root request body of the Open API Spec
I am generating java model and client classes from an Open Api Spec using open api generator.
Everything generates fine, compiles and tests run fine.
However, I see in the spec examples the request body looks like e.g. this:
{
  "topLevelField" : 
    {
      "id" : "ABC123", 
      "name" : "Jon Doe",
.....  
    }
}

However, my api client class seems to have as it's input not the root object but the object of field "topLevelField". I.e.:
    ResponseEntity<Void> createAgreementV1(@Valid @RequestBody RootAgreementCreate rootAgreementCreate);

Where RootAgreementCreate is like:
    @Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-05-06T17:57:05.828976700+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]", comments = "Generator version: 7.5.0")
public class RootAgreementCreate {

  private String id;
  private String name;
...
...

So the spec expects a object which has a property "topLevelField" which is an instance of type RootAgreementCreate, but the client api classes generator by the generator set this type directly as the request body.
I feel like this is probably something very simple I'm overlooking because I can't be the first to encounter this, but I can't find any clues in the configs.
Is it related to the json library I'm using?

Java 17
Springboot 3.1.9
Maven
OpenApi Generator maven plugin 7.5.0

Here is my openapi maven config:
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-agreement-create-clients</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/contracts/openapi/oas-agreement-create.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.example.api.arrangement</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.example.api.arrangement.model</modelPackage>
                            <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                            <configOptions>
                                <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                                <documentationProvider>none</documentationProvider>
                                <basePackage>com.example.api</basePackage>
                                <configPackage>com.example.api.client.rest.agreement</configPackage>
                                <library>spring-cloud</library>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

What I want is something like a request type which encapsulates the RootAgreementCreate in a field "topLevelField" and have this as input to my api client code:
public class AgreementCreateRequest {

   private RootAgreementCreate topLevelField;
....
}

I just can't seem to get the generator to create it like this.
Any suggestions are appreciated.
